# Change Spring Data REST exposing link

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

By default, Spring Data REST will expose search resources to urls under `{resource_name}/search`. For example, `findBySubject_Id` in the following code will be exposed to `{baseUrl}/questions/search/findBySubject_Id?subjectId={subjectId}`.

```java
public interface QuestionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Question, String> {
    Page<Question> findBySubject_Id(@Param("subjectId")String subjectId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

For compatiblility reasons, I need the exposing link to be `{baseUrl}/questions?subjectId={subjectId}`. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not override /search url. If you really need a link without search, you should override [response handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) for the entity via writing your own controller with annotation [@RepositoryRestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestController.html)